# Simplifying a directory string

Tags: php, html

Take the following directory structure:

- Parent1

  - Child folder

    - Child Folder 1
    - Child Folder 2

The path to Child Folder 2 would be:

```
Parent/Child folder/Child Folder 2
```

But, another valid path can also be

```
Parent/Child folder/Child Folder 1/../Child Folder 2
```

Is there a way to "Simplify" the path, or convert a path such as:

```
Parent/Child folder/Child Folder 1/../Child Folder 2
```

to

```
Parent/Child folder/Child Folder 2
```

I was trying to find a way to extract the file name from the handle that `opendir($directory)` gives you, but I haven't found a way to do this yet. I'm also pretty sure there must be some terminology or better wording than "simplify", but I did not know what to search for. "Simplify path" php didn't help much.

Edit:

I've noticed realpath gives me the complete, full path. It does not give you the relative one, as in `Parent/Child folder/Child Folder 2`, but `C:\Path\To\Server\Directory\Parent\Child Folder\Child Folder 2`
That's a bit disappointing, but I can convert it back with some string manipulation.

Comment: Wow, four good answers all within a few seconds of each other! Gotta love stackoverflow :)

Comment: *"I'm also pretty sure there must be some terminology or better wording"* I've typically seen this referred to as "path normalization".

Comment: Grrr... You guys are too fast!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the path actually exists, you can use [`realpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) to resolve relative path portions. It also resolves symbolic links.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`realpath()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)

```
$path = realpath('Parent/Child folder/Child Folder 1/../Child Folder 2');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with function [`realpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php).